# Converting a GroupJoin statement to an Expression Tree

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, system.reflection

I'm attempting to do an outer join on two sets of data using this statement:

```
var destinationList = inners.GroupJoin(outers, inner => inner.JoinField, outer => outer.JoinField,
    (inner, outerList) =>
        outerList.Select(outer => new DestinationModel { Id = inner.JoinField, AggregationField = outer.DataField })
            .DefaultIfEmpty(new DestinationModel { Id = inner.JoinField })).SelectMany(destination => destination).ToList();
```

This works correctly without problem, but I ultimately need to convert this to an expression tree to allow the datasets and the fields to change.

My data models look like this:

InnerModel:
    public class InnerModel
    {
        public int JoinField;
        public decimal DataField;
    }

OuterModel:
    public class OuterModel
    {
        public int JoinField;
        public decimal DataField;
    }

DestinationModel:
    public class DestinationModel
    {
        public int Id;
        public decimal AggregationField;
    }

inners is a `List<InnerModel>`

outers is a `List<OuterModel>`

I've managed to get most of the way, but I'm falling short at the last step.  This is what I have so far:

```
// Declare variables
var innerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (InnerModel), "inner");
var innerSelect = Expression.Lambda<Func<InnerModel, int>>(Expression.Field(innerParameter, "JoinField"), innerParameter);
var outerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (OuterModel), "outer");
var outerListParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (IEnumerable<OuterModel>), "outerList");
var outerSelect = Expression.Lambda<Func<OuterModel, int>>(Expression.Field(outerParameter, "JoinField"), outerParameter);
var existingBinding = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof (DestinationModel)), Expression.Bind(typeof (DestinationModel).GetField("Id"), Expression.Field(innerParameter, "JoinField"))); 

// Create lambdas
var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<OuterModel, DestinationModel>>(existingBinding, outerParameter);
var selectMethod = typeof (Enumerable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Select" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(OuterModel), typeof(DestinationModel));
var selectCall = Expression.Call(selectMethod, outerListParameter, selector);

// Create the inner key selector for the GroupJoin method
var innerKeySelector = Expression.Lambda(selectCall, innerParameter, outerListParameter);
```

Everything works up until this point.  When I try to plug the innerKeySelector into the original statement:

```
var result = inners.GroupJoin(outers, innerSelect.Compile(), outerSelect.Compile(), (inner, outerList) => outerList.Select(outer => new DestinationModel {Id = inner.JoinField, AggregationField = outer.DataField}).DefaultIfEmpty(new DestinationModel {Id = inner.JoinField})).SelectMany(destination => destination).ToList();
```

I get a compile error:

The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.GroupJoin(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, Func, Func, Func, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I know I'm just missing something obvious, but after working on this for hours, I'm not seeing it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Except that had to rename model classes to `xxxTestModel`, I don't get any compiler error with the posted code.

Comment: I fixed the names of the classes in the code, and simplified some of the calls, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.  I needed to place the DefaultIfEmpty call and give it the result of the Select call.  I created a MethodInfo for the DefaultIfEmpty call:

```
var defaultIfEmptyMethod = typeof (Enumerable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "DefaultIfEmpty" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof (DestinationTestModel));
```

Then I created a lambda expression that calls DefaultIfEmpty and Select together:

```
var innerKeySelectorWithDefault = Expression.Lambda<Func<InnerTestModel,IEnumerable<OuterTestModel>,IEnumerable<DestinationTestModel>>>(Expression.Call(defaultIfEmptyMethod, selectCall, nonExistingBinding), innerParameter, outerListParameter);
```

That enabled me to call the final methods:

```
var result = inners.GroupJoin(outers, innerSelect.Compile(), outerSelect.Compile(),innerKeySelectorWithDefault.Compile()).SelectMany(destination => destination).ToList();
```